# Unable to create JPA/CRUDRepository bean

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am creating first-time spring rest services with Spring Data JPA.

and getting below error.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field product_repo in com.example.demo.controller.AddProduct required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.ProductRepositroy' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.ProductRepositroy' in your configuration.

My class and interfaces are :

1. Controller

```
@RestController
public class AddProduct {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepositroy product_repo;
    
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addproduct() {
        
        
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setId(1);
        p1.setName("Amit");
        
        
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p1.setId(2);
        p1.setName("Sumit");
        
        
        product_repo.save(p1);
        product_repo.save(p2);
        
        
        return "added successfully the recod";
        
    }

}
```

2. Entity

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    

}
```

3. Repository

```
public interface ProductRepositroy extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

4. Application Test

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: If possible .. can you please mention the package names of classes or add your project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Add **@Repository** annotation on ProductRepositroy interface. Also instead of extending CrudRepository extend **JpaRepository**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Repository` in the repository to register this class in the bean.

Code should be something like this.

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepositroy extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

happy coding! :)